# Adding ints as a string does not output correct value

Tags: python

```
import time
import random
print("Hi user, what is your name?")
name = input()
print("Right "+name," lets get on!")
time.sleep(1)
number1 = random.randrange(1, 50)
number2 = random.randrange(1, 50)
print("What is " + str(number1) + "+" + str(number2))
response = input()
answer = str(number1) + str(number2)
if response == answer:
    print("Welldone " + name + "That's Right!")
elif response != answer:
    print("I'm afraid that's wrong, maybe next time!")
```

Even if the answer is right it outputs: "I'm afraid that's wrong, maybe next time!"

Comment: Adding strings does not act the same way adding numbers does. Try printing both `response` and `answer`, and the bug will be obvious.

Comment: Could you please edit your post so that your code becomes more readible? There is something called "new line"...

Comment: Not giving your post a meaningful title would my first guess.  Confusing string concatenation with numeric addition would be my second.

Comment: Just add the numbers together to get the answer. Don't convert them to strings first.

Comment: Rather than `elif response != answer` you can simply use `else` - if the two items don't compare equal, they must, by definition, be not equal. No need to compare again to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `str(number1) + str(number2)` you are adding two strings together, so you get `"25" + "30"` which gives you `"2530"`. You want to do the conversion to a string *after* you add the numbers.

```
str(number1 + number2)
```

When you encounter a problem like this, you know that the `if`'s clause  `response == answer` must be returning `False`. To debug, try printing out both sides of the equality and checking them - it would make a bug like this very obvious.

Comment: Ahh. At first blush this was strictly a throwing-out-fish answer as opposed to a teaching-to-fish one. Significantly improved as edited.

Answer (score 0):

On the teach-a-man-to-fish front, let's look at the problem:

```
if response == answer:
    print("Welldone " + name + "That's Right!")
elif response != answer:
    print("I'm afraid that's wrong, maybe next time!")
```

Clearly *you* think response and answer should be equal, while the computer says they are not.  Well, what are the values?  Either "response" isn't what you think (for example, it has spaces or newlines in it), or "answer" isn't what you think (for example, it is "2530" instead of "55"), or both.

If you add

```
print response, answer
```

before the if statement, you will probably achieve enlightenment.